# How to join multiple tables with LEFT JOIN

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have three entities defines as follows:

```
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vault_id")
    private Vault vault;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_vault_id")
    private Vault contactVault;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "vault")
public class Vault {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private User owner;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"User\"")
public abstract class User {
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String uuid;

}
```

I can't figure out how to replace the following native query:

```
FROM Contact contact
     LEFT JOIN contact.vault v
     LEFT JOIN contact.contactVault cv
     WHERE contact.accepted = true
     AND v.owner.uuid= :uuid
...
// other clauses omitted for easier reading
```

I created the `ContactSpecification`as follows but was stuck with on how to join multiple tables:

```
public class ContactSpecifications {
    private ContactSpecifications() {
    }

public static Specification<Contact> allContactsAndVaults(String uuid) {
  List<Predicate> joinsList = new ArrayList<>();
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<Contact, Vault> vaultJoin = root.join(Contact_.VAULT, JoinType.LEFT);
            Join<Contact, Vault> contactVaultJoin =  root.join(Contact_.CONTACT_VAULT, JoinType.LEFT);

           // TODO
// SHOULD the above joins be used in some way?
// The below will fail!!!!
             joinsList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(vaultJoin.get("id"), Contact_.VAULT));
            joinsList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(contactVaultJoin.get("id"), Contact_.CONTACT_VAULT));
            Predicate[] p = new Predicate[joinsList.size()];
            return criteriaBuilder.and(joinsList.toArray(p));
        };
    }
```

Modifying as follows will also fail:

```
public static Specification<Contact> allContactsAndVaults(String uuid) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            root.join(Contact.VAULT, JoinType.LEFT);
            root.join(Contact.CONTACT_VAULT, JoinType.LEFT);
           
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Vault.OWNER).get("uuid"), uuid);
        };
    }
```

Any clues?

**UPDATE-1**
The below seems to work:

```
    public static Specification<Contact> allContactsAndVaults(String uuid) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<Contact, Vault> vaultJoin = root.join(Contact_.VAULT, JoinType.LEFT);
            root.join(Contact_.CONTACT_VAULT, JoinType.LEFT);
            vaultJoin.join(Vault_.OWNER);

            return criteriaBuilder.equal(vaultJoin.get("owner").get("uuid"), uuid);
        };
    }
```

The question is how to add the following criteria later on:
`AND (:contactType IS NULL OR cv.owner.role = :contactType)`.

I tried to create a new static method returning a specification:

```
public static Specification<Contact> hasContactTypeLike(ContactType contactType) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            if (contactType == null) {
                return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Vault_.OWNER).get("role"), contactType.name());
        };
    }
```

So that the whole call could be as follows:

```
contactJpaRepository.findAll(allContactsAndVaultsByPublicId(publicId.getValue())
                                             .and(withContactAccepted())
                                             .and(hasContactTypeLike(contactType))
);
```

but it failed with:
`Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [owner] on this ManagedType [som.package.entities.Contact]`

Still no clues.

**UPDATE-2**

When using this way to access the related entities works:

```
public static Specification<Contact> hasContactTypeLike(ContactType contactType) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            if (contactType == null) {
                return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
            }
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("contactVault").get("owner").get("role"), contactType.name());
        };
    }
```

but adds an extra CROSS JOIN to the generated SQL:

```
select contactent0_.id as id1_6_, contactent0_.accepted as accepted2_6_, contactent0_.contact_vault_id as contact_4_6_, contactent0_.created_on as created_3_6_, contactent0_.vault_id as vault_id5_6_ 
from contact contactent0_ left outer join vault vaultentit1_ on contactent0_.vault_id=vaultentit1_.id 
inner join "user" userentity2_ on vaultentit1_.owner_id=userentity2_.id 
left outer join vault vaultentit3_ on contactent0_.contact_vault_id=vaultentit3_.id 
cross join "user" userentity6_ 
where vaultentit3_.owner_id=userentity6_.id and userentity2_.public_user_id=? and contactent0_.accepted=? and userentity6_.role=?
```

**Update-3 (failing)**

One more obstacle popped up. The problem is do inheritance: `User` being abstract class, does not have all the attributes defines in its child classes:

- `Citizen`
- `Study`

I tried to cast by using `treat` method as follows:

```
 public static Specification<Contact> withDeceasedNotification(Boolean enabled) {

return new Specification<Contact>() {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Contact> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                Path<Citizen> citizenUserRoot = criteriaBuilder.treat(root.get(Contact_.CONTACT_VAULT).get(Vault_.OWNER), Citizen.class);

...
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.or(
                                    criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(citizenUserRoot.get(Citizen_.DECEASED_NOTIFICATION_DATE))
                            )
                    );
```

but it failed with:

```
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [deceasedNotificationDate] on this ManagedType [my.package.entities.User]
```